# How to implement a generic Factory that supports template covariance?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dependency-injection, c++14, factory

I want to achieve something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Factory<BaseClass>> factory = 
    std::make_shared<Factory<DerivedClass>>();

auto x = factory->create(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Note that in `factory->create`, you can pass any arguments to `DerivedClass` constructor. It is okay to assume that the `BaseClass` constructor and the `DerivedClass` are identical.

---

To avoid the XY Problem, the reason I need this is because I want to use dependency injection ([boost::di](https://github.com/boost-experimental/di)) to achieve maximum testability.

For example, if there's a class `A` that creates `Socket` instances, I want it to depend on a `Factory<ISocket>` service. In the real code, I'd inject `Factory<Socket>`, and in the testing code, I'd inject `Factory<Mock<ISocket>>`, so I can test the `A` class without actually creating a real socket.

---

This is my current attempt:

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseFactory {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> create() = 0;
};

template <typename TInterface, typename TImplementation>
struct Factory : public BaseFactory<TInterface> {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<TInterface> create() override {
        return std::make_unique<TImplementation>();  
    }
};
```

The current usage is something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseFactory<ISocket>> factory = 
    std::make_shared<Factory<ISocket, Socket>>();

auto x = factory->create();
```

Although not ideal (you need to specify the base class in `Factory`), this usage is fine for me and it works.

The next thing I need to add is support for constructor arguments. I've tried to add variadic template to `create`:

```
template <typename ...TArgs>
virtual std::unique_ptr<T> create() = 0;
```

... but it looks like you can't have virtual methods with templates.

Am I going in the right direction? If yes, how should I add support for constructor arguments in my implementation?

Comment: I'm pretty confused here. Is the code meant to compile? This won't work since `create()` has a `void` return type and I can't see how you would make this work as the virtual function needs the same return type as its parents'.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper sorry, is it clearer now?

Comment: You said "it works", but again as I said your code doesn't compile. Can you post an MCVE?

Comment: I think my main point of confusion here is whether you intend to inject the Mock object in the creation of the `factory()` object, or in the `create()` function inside factory.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Here you go: https://ideone.com/xpt38h

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I want to inject the Mock object (or the real object) in the creation of the `factory` object. In the real world, you'd have a class that accepts a `Factory<Interface>` service, and a DI framework that injects `Factory<Mock<Interface>>` to it.

Comment: Does the derived `factory`'s create *need* to be virtual?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper not necessarily

Comment: There you go then.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper How does making the factory's create method not virtual helps? Remember that I want to be able to call `BaseFactory<ISocket>::create()` and get a `Mock<ISocket>` (or `Socket`) object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for [boost::di](http://boost-experimental.github.io/di/index.html):

http://boost-experimental.github.io/di/extensions/index.html#factory

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found one solution, but it's not pretty:

```
template <typename T, typename ...TArgs>
struct BaseFactory {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<T> create(TArgs&&... args) = 0;
};

template <typename TInterface, typename TImplementation, typename ...TArgs>
struct Factory : public BaseFactory<TInterface, TArgs...> {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<TInterface> create(TArgs&&... args) override {
        return std::make_unique<TImplementation>(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    }
};

using ISocketFactory = BaseFactory<ISocket, int>;
using SocketFactory = Factory<ISocket, Socket, int>;

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketFactory> socket_factory = 
        std::make_shared<SocketFactory>();

    std::unique_ptr<ISocket> socket = socket_factory->create(1234);
    socket->read();
    socket->write();
}
```

The idea is to pass the implementation class' constructor arguments in the `BaseFactory` and `Factory` templates. In this case, the `Socket` constructor should look something like:

```
Socket(int n);
```

Do you have any idea how to optimize this? (less boilerplate code)